# how to start with sql server reporting services

Tags: reportingservices-2005

I want to start learning SSRS, that is sql server reporting services. How should I start for my test application? I have simply installed sql server 2005 and visual studio 3.5 and IIS 6.0. What else do I need to configure in order to start with SSRS and do I need to install any tool kit? Is there any compatibility issues with sql server?

I need to make some print report using ssrs.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2005 includes all the tools necessary to configure SSRS on your computer. Just check under your Programs folder and configure SSRS using the Reporting Services Configuration under the "Configuration Tools" menu group. Run through the configuration wizard and everything should be up and running soon enough. You don't need to install any other toolkits...

By saying you have "visual studio 3.5" installed, I assume you mean Visual Studio with .NET Framework 3.5, right? When you have SSRS installed and Visual Studio 2005 (or higher), you'll find the Reporting Services project under the "Business Intelligence" group of Project Types.

Once you get started, just scour the web for a couple of tutorials. There are many good ones readily available. A quick search on your favourite search engine should immediately yield good results...